# Resize windows in Texmaker editor

Tags: texmaker, editors, resize

I want to resize the structure window in Texmaker to make it smaller so I can have a better view of the source and pdf viewer windows. I can currently resize it to a point but I want to be able to make it smaller, ie. there seems to be some limit on the width of the windows.
Does anyone know how to change this limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open in the menu »View«, there you can (un)check »Structure«, which makes the structure view (dis)appear. Maybe this can be connected to a shortcut, but I couldn't find out, how to do this.

No other customisation possible in the GUI regarding the structure view.